# Why is the width of toast shorter than its content?

Tags: android, toast

I wrote an activity which contains a navigation drawer (a simple fragment with a ListView inside), and a model and an adapter for the ListView. There is an ImageView and a TextView in a single list item, as it's usually be in many apps. That's all I have done, and the rest codes of the activity and fragment's classes were all generated automatically by Android Studio. Then when I used `Toast.makeText` in the activity, the result looks as [this](http://pic.yupoo.com/bitex/DRT3CLsE/neisl.png).

I've searched for this question and tried using `Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), ...)` instead of `Toast.makeText(this, ...)`, and it worked. I'm wondering why would this happen and how should I solved this problem correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) it says that a typical Toast looks like this:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
```

I imagine it is because depending on the class you have, the context varies because not all context instances are created equal.

More info also [here](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/):

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't even know that's the correct usage as it is.