# Why is the width of toast too short?

Tags: android, toast

Days ago I asked a question ["Why is the width of toast shorter than its content?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475333/why-is-the-width-of-toast-shorter-than-its-content). In that question I found the width of my toasts became so short that it could not even contain all the words inside it, and lately I knew that if I use `Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), ...` the width of toast will come back to normal.

But today I found that the toasts created by the app itself went wrong again. As is shown in [this screenshot](http://pic.yupoo.com/bitex/DS3Tebp0/Osq42.png), if I long-press the action bar button, its name will be shown in a toast automatically by the app, but obviously the width of the toast is shorter than usual.

I've narrowed the problem down to that it's because I used a translucent StatusBar which is supported in KitKat. I put these lines of code inside my `res\values-v19\styles.xml`:

```xml
<item name="android.windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

for a better visual effect, and if I remove these two lines from the file, the toast will come back to normal. Why would this happen? Is there any solution to use translucent StatusBar and normal toasts together?

Comment: isn't it related to issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63653 ?

Comment: no problem, added answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem related to: code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63653

As in link :

```
Using getApplicationContext() is a workaround but see post above.
```